# Artifacts in the solutions of NSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex, precision-and-accuracy

I have (what I think are) some problems with the precision of NSolve.

I'm trying to solve this cubic equation:

$a f^3(x)-b f^2(x)-c f(x)-z=0$

for the function $f(x)$ and then plot the following curve:

$\rho(z)=-\frac{1}{z\pi}\Im f^2(x)$

I wrote this piece of code in mathematica (the exact coefficients are not important for now):

```
NSolve[5000 (f[z])^3 - 300 z (f[z])^2 + (600 + z^2) f[z] - z == 0, f[z]]
Plot[-(1/(z π)) Im[(f[z] /. %[[3]])^2 ], {z, -20, 20}]
Plot[-(1/(z π)) Im[(f[z] /. %%[[2]])^2 ], {z, -20, 20}]
```

the first solution being the real one I'm not interested to. I already know what the shape of the right curve should be, but the results are ruined by an artifact:

[image: First Solution]

[image: Second solution]

The first curve should be symmetric and smoothly decrease to zero, and the second should be its reflection through the x-axis.

How can I eliminate this artifact? I tried increasing the WorkingPrecision

```
NSolve[5000 (f[z])^3 - 300 z (f[z])^2 + (600 + z^2) f[z] - z == 0, f[z], 
       WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

and setting a higher precision for the equation

```
FindRoot[
 SetPrecision[5000 (f[z])^3 - 300 z (f[z])^2 + (600 + z^2) f[z] - z == 0, 30], f[z]]
```

but the results are the same.

I also tried with other methods: FindRoot requires a starting point that I can't give (the solutions being functions and not numbers) and NDSolve rightly replies that there are no derivates.

This problem is just the starting point: later I will have to solve a polynomial equation for $f(x)$ given by

$f(z)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\mu_i}{z-\mu_i f(x)}$

where $\mu_i$ are numerical coefficients. Some early attempts result in even worse cut-offs (everything except a small part of the curve around the y-axis)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: 1) This equation can be solved analytically, so don't use `NSolve`, use `Solve` instead, and add `Cubics -> False` as an option to `Solve` to work with the more reliable `Root` objects: `Solve[5000 (f[z])^3 - 300 z (f[z])^2 + (600 + z^2) f[z] - z == 0, f[z], Cubics -> False]`. Your own plotting expressions then return [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fX1oE.png) and [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KaiE5.png).

Comment: Thanks! Just using Solve fixed the problem in the first case. However, in the general case I briefly sketched at the end of my post, the cut-offs return when the sum has approximately more than 30 terms.

If $m$ is the  vector of the coefficients, my equation is:

    eq = f[z] == Sum[m[[i]]/(z - m[[i]] f[z]), {i, 31}]

With Solve, it first gives me this error: 

"Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result."

and then it plots this curve: i.imgur.com/EHPqJzS.jpg . Do you know why?

Comment: It does not look like an artifact. Rather it appears to involve crossings of the roots as `z` varies.

Comment: Shouldn't the solution of the polynomial be continuous? The other solution is the same (but negative).

Comment: Also, in my first comment i didn't write the normalization in the equation (the factor $\frac{1}{N})$. If I add it the cut-off is [even worse](http://i.imgur.com/EWGWlZV.jpg)

Comment: The solution depends on a parameter, `z`. Root functions are ordered in some way, and may cross for specific parameter values. When that happens one gets seeming discontinuities. The ensemble of root objects is continuous, in an appopriate space, but the individual ones are not. Nor can they be mde everywhere continuous; there must be branch points and thus branch cuts.